# Return zero when list contains negatives

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How do I create a function of a list, such that if any member of the list is negative it is zero, otherwise it follows a recursion relation.

Mathematically this is what I have to do, but I'm not sure how to do it in Mathematica.

Thanks.

Edit: To be completely precise, I am trying to implement the recursion relation on page 6 of this paper (eq 18):
http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/nlin/pdf/0003/0003069v1.pdf

However, it's quite complicated and requires a fair amount of reading to understand, so I didn't want to bring it into the question!

Comment: What recursion relation? Could you add it to the question?

Comment: There you go. Equation 18 on page 6 of the given paper.

Comment: I think that's a different proposition than what your question implies, so I'm glad you posted it. Complex, of course; doable, probably.

Comment: @Volatile you're right, it is hard to understand what is to be done by looking at eq 18. For instance, there is a sum over vectors mu and theta, constrained such that mu+theta=nu. I assume this means \sum_{\nu_1}\sum_{\nu_2} etc; but what is the range? from 1 to what?  and what does nu(i) mean in the subscript to the U in the last sum? the ith component?

Comment: I think implementing the recursion relation is another question

Comment: The "vector" nu is an infinite dimensional vector of integers (therefore not really making it a vector space, but still). nu(i) is the vector nu with the alteration of -1 from the ith component and +1 in the i+1th component. (It is all in the paper, but there's a lot of reading). 
With regards to the sum, that's the one bit I have figured out!

And perhaps the recursion relation is indeed another question but it's so complicated I wanted to break it down into component parts to solve it - this is one of them.

Comment: Here's the full implementation - http://pastebin.com/NfwzPCm1
Turns out what I was looking for was these conditional patterns. It's about 100 times faster than my old method!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing if any member of a list satisfies some condition can be done using [MemberQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MemberQ.html). To test if the list `lst` contains any element less than zero,

```
lst = {1, 2, 0, -4};
MemberQ[lst, x_ /; x < 0]
```

The second argument here is a [conditional pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html).

But yes, knowing what it is you want to do would help.

Comment: The conditional patters were what I was looking for, thankyou!

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach:

```
g[l_List /; Min[g] >= 0] := (* recursion relation *)
g[l_List] := 0
```

Comment: Strangely, this version is faster than the pattern-matching case in my original answer, but not the version with a conditional.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the function using a conditional test so that if all the elements are non-negative, the recursion relation is used.

```
 f[l_List] /; And @@ NonNegative[l] := (* recursion relation *)
```

Then the more general case only applies if not all the elements are non-negative, i.e. some are negative or zero.

```
 f[l_List] := 0
```

An even easier method using pattern-matching

```
 fff[l:{__?NonNegative}]:= (* recursion relation *)

 fff[l_List]:= 0
```

---

**EDIT**

It turns out that the method I first proposed is the most efficient.

```
ff[l_list] /; And @@ NonNegative[l] := True

ff[l_List] := 0
```

Brett's version

```
gg[l_List] /; Min[l] > 0 := True

gg[l_List] := False
```

My second proposal

```
hh[l : {__?NonNegative}] := True

hh[l_List] := False
```

A variant on my second proposal that focussed on finding the negatives rather than not finding them, if that makese sense.

```
jj[l : {___, _?Negative, ___}] := False

jj[l_List] := True
```

There should only be a few negatives in this case

```
testfg = RandomInteger[{-1, 1000}, 10000];
```

A case with lots of negatives: some pattern matchers shouldn't need to scan the whole list

```
testfg1 = RandomInteger[{-1, 4}, 10000];
```

This one should return True

```
testfg2 = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, 10000];
```

Now to test:

```
ff[testfg] // Timing

{0.000016, 0}

ff[testfg1] // Timing

{0.000015, 0}

ff[testfg2] // Timing

{0.000024, 0}
```

Brett's version is a little slower, but second-fastest overall

```
gg[testfg] // Timing

{0.000049, True}

gg[testfg1] // Timing

{0.000049, True}

gg[testfg2] // Timing

{0.00005, True}

hh[testfg] // Timing

{0.000271, False}

hh[testfg1] // Timing

{0.000234, False}

hh[testfg2] // Timing

{0.003809, True}

jj[testfg] // Timing

{0.002482, False}
```

Sure enough, this version is fast if there are a lot of negative numbers and it doesn't have to check the whole list.

```
jj[testfg1] // Timing

{0.0005, False}
```

But it is extremely inefficient if there are no negative numbers because of the expansiveness of the pattern

```
jj[testfg2] // Timing

{0.678945, True}
```

Comment: @acl I always forget that it is available (and has been since version 1), even though I use `?Positive` patterns all the time. I did it the first way because I momentarily forgot `NonNegative` would work and was trying some compound `(0|Positive)` pattern using `Alternative`. But I always have trouble getting those kinds of patterns to work.

Comment: @Verbeia on version 7 Brett's method tests about 20X faster than your first with this data:  `SeedRandom[1]; lst = RandomInteger[{-1, 1*^6}, {3*^6}];` how does it compare on your system?